# When should I use a Map in my data model?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, model

I am developing a `java` web application using `MongoDB` as my database.
While modeling my data objects, I was wondering when should I use a `Map` and when to create another object.

For example, let's say I have a `User` that contains roles, and a `Role` model.
I can write the User in a way that it contains a `Map <String, Role>`, or a list of roles.

```
user: {
  roles: {
    admin: {
      key1: value,
      key2: value
    },
    ...
  }
}

user: {
  roles: [{
    id: admin,
    key1: value,
    key2: value
  },
  ...
}
```

While the first way seems more comfortable for a client to access the roles (user.role.admin), I tend to prefer the second solution since it can be expanded easier and I can avoid crazy nested `map`s like `<String, Map<String, Map<String, MyModel>>>`.
How should I model my data, and when should my models contain `Map`s?

Comment: You can allways implement the "more comfortable" solution as a transient getter method that constructs its map on the fly from the data that you actually use to store it. Using Transient methods you can even hide your actual data structure by making it private and only the transient methods public.

Comment: But from design point of view, should I ever use a map or another model? It feels wrong to have a model that contains a map (JSON equivalent)